# Executing multiple (wget) commands in Mac Terminal properly?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, wget

I'm trying to execute a long list of repetitive commands on Terminal.

The commands look like this:

```
wget 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/localstarlight.hl2o31b8/-180,52,9/1280x1280.png' -O '/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.-180) 0.png' \ 
wget 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/localstarlight.hl2o31b8/-177,52,9/1280x1280.png' -O '/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.-177) 1.png' \
```

If I copy the entire list into Terminal, it executes them all but seems to do it in such a rush that some only get partially downloadeed, and some missed out entirely. It doesn't seem to take them one by one and wait until each is finished before attempting the next.

I tried putting them entire list into a shell script and running it, but then for some reason it seems to download everything, but only produces one file, and looking at the output, it seems to be trying to save each file under the same filename:

```
2014-03-29 09:56:31 (4.15 MB/s) - `/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.180) 120.png' saved [28319/28319]

    --2014-03-29 09:56:31--  http://%20%0Dwget/
    Resolving  \rwget... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
    wget: unable to resolve host address ` \rwget'
    --2014-03-29 09:56:31--  http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/localstarlight.hl2o31b8/171,52,9/1280x1280.png
    Reusing existing connection to api.tiles.mapbox.com:80.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 33530 (33K) [image/jpeg]
    Saving to: `/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.180) 120.png'

    100%[======================================>] 33,530      --.-K/s   in 0.008s  

    2014-03-29 09:56:31 (3.90 MB/s) - `/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.180) 120.png' saved [33530/33530]

    --2014-03-29 09:56:31--  http://%20%0Dwget/
    Resolving  \rwget... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
    wget: unable to resolve host address ` \rwget'
    --2014-03-29 09:56:31--  http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/localstarlight.hl2o31b8/174,52,9/1280x1280.png
    Reusing existing connection to api.tiles.mapbox.com:80.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 48906 (48K) [image/jpeg]
    Saving to: `/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.180) 120.png'

    100%[======================================>] 48,906      --.-K/s   in 0.01s   

    2014-03-29 09:56:31 (4.88 MB/s) - `/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.180) 120.png' saved [48906/48906]

    --2014-03-29 09:56:31--  http://%20%0Dwget/
    Resolving  \rwget... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
    wget: unable to resolve host address ` \rwget'
    --2014-03-29 09:56:31--  http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/localstarlight.hl2o31b8/177,52,9/1280x1280.png
    Reusing existing connection to api.tiles.mapbox.com:80.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 45644 (45K) [image/jpeg]
    Saving to: `/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.180) 120.png'

    100%[======================================>] 45,644      --.-K/s   in 0.01s   

    2014-03-29 09:56:31 (4.36 MB/s) - `/Volumes/Alaya/XXXXXXXX/Downloads/MapTiles/Tile (52.180) 120.png' saved [45644/45644]
```

So it's saving every file to this name: *Tile (52.180) 120.png*

Note that it doesn't do this if I put in each command separately...so I don't understand why it's doing that.

Can someone tell me how to execute this list of commands so that it does each one properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/localstarlight.hl2o31b8/-180,52,9/1280x1280.png' -O 'a.png'
wget -q 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/localstarlight.hl2o31b8/-177,52,9/1280x1280.png' -O 'b.png'
```

BUT... you have a backslash at the end of each `wget` line, which is a continuation character for long lines and which you don't need. Remove it.

Essentially you are asking wget to get a file and then another file called wget and then another file and then another file. Your script only does a single `wget` - the first one. All the other `wget` commands are seen as parameters to the first `wget` because of the continuation character.

You are doing this:

```
wget URL file wget URL file wget URL file
```

Comment: Answer updated - please copy and paste and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the log you've posted:

```
http://%20%0Dwget/
```

This suggests that your script contains <kbd>CR</kbd>+<kbd>LF</kbd> line endings.  Remove those before executing the script:

```
sed $'s/\r//' scriptname
```

or

```
tr -d '\r' < scriptname
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, it still tried to save everything to that same file (Tile (52.180) 120.png). Oddly, the filesize just keeps increasing, even though the image just shows the first image, as if it's just appending the extra png content to the original one... Any idea why it's not saving to each filename specified in the wget command?

Comment: @kinkersnick ...because you didn't do what I suggested in the other answer maybe?

Comment: Both of those commands you put seem to just list the commands from the script in the Terminal window, not execute them. By removing the '\' from each line of the script myself, it now runs, but like I said it just keeps adding to the same file. I'm obviously not understanding what you're suggesting, sorry!